# Linq selecting from muliple tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following model

```
public class SummaryModel
{
    public int CompanyCount { get; set; }
    public int GroupCount { get; set; }
    public int ProjectCount { get; set; }
    public int ResourcesCount { get; set; }
    public int PeopleCount { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use linq to query my database and return record counts from multiple tables and populate this model object.

This is how I am doing it:

```
        using (var ctx = new WeWorkModel.weWorkEntities())
        {
            var summary = new SummaryModel()
                {
                    CompanyCount = ctx.Companies.Count(),
                    PeopleCount = ctx.People.Count(),
                    GroupCount = ctx.Groups.Count(),
                    ProjectCount = ctx.Projects.Count(),
                    ResourcesCount = ctx.Resources.Count()
                };

        }
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: There's hardly an alternative. The counts will be the most expensive part anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the most efficient way - equivalent to writing sql query as this does not fetch the objects but only does a count on the server. So something like this ( using profiler I tracked the query)

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store this model in a database or change it's values after instantiating? If no, why not put this code block inside of a parameterless constructor and mark the fields readonly as to avoid using this model differently than intended. If you find later you need greater control over initialization of fields, simply add another constructor to deal with that specific case. To the main question, I see nothing particularly inefficient with your way of handling it. Although, with code there is nearly always terser ways or more efficient ways of handling just about any scenario.